# How can I access the for-loop variable outside the loop in PHP?

Tags: php, for-loop

I have a for loop in PHP and want to access the `$f` variable outside the loop. Is there a certain way to do this? I searched for the answer but can't find the right one.

```
foreach($dirlist as $f) {

}

filemtime($f)
```

**Update:**

I just went the more simple way and ended up doing this:

```
date('M d, Y', filemtime(getcwd().'/index.php'))
```

Comment: Are you aware that the `$f` will be the last element in the array?

Comment: Which `$f`? Each iteration will have different `$f`.

Comment: Its not possible @Mike you will be getting only the last element from the array...

Comment: Why arent you using `filemtime` in loop? Could you clarify, what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Mike why such type of requirement please explain?

Comment: I think you are looping through that array to meet some criteria, and you want to access the matched one outside the loop, don't you?

Comment: ok I have a script that checks the folders in the root for index files. I use it to create my nav menu on the fly. I am adding this to the page `<p class="post-info">This article was last reviewed on <? echo '<time itemprop="dateModified" datetime="'.date('Y-m-d', filemtime($f)).'">'. date('M d, Y', filemtime($f)).'</time>'; ?></p>` So, instead of hitting the server again for the file to get the filemtime of it, I thought I'd just access the information from the for loop I already have.

Comment: @someOne that is correct

Comment: @Mike, Are you aware that you don't hit the server *again*? All PHP code runs on the server (on every HTTP request). If you want to specify more (which you should, your question is too vague) you should edit your question and write a clarification note to specify exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Add your `filemtime` results to the new array and retrieve last modified date by file name.

```
<?php
// Array of modified dates, file names as keys
$modifiedDates = array();

foreach($dirlist as $f) {
  $modifiedDates[basename($f)] = filemtime($f);
}

// File name to look modified time again (just file name, no path)
// basename function gets file name from path
$filename = basename( $pathToFile );
$lastModified = $modifiedDates[$filename];
?>
<p class="post-info">This article was last reviewed on <?php echo '<time itemprop="dateModified" datetime="'.date('Y-m-d', $lastModified).'">'. date('M d, Y', $lastModified).'</time>'; ?></p>
```

Comment: I ended up simply using this `date('M d, Y', filemtime(getcwd().'/index.php'))`

Comment: But your question was not to use `filemtime` on this file again. Though your solution dosen't answer the question. I understand that this way worked for you, but you should stick to your question "How can I access the for-loop variable outside the loop in PHP?".

Comment: I would like to know how to but can't figure it out. So I did what was easier. My question seems pretty simple. I just want to know how to, after looping through the array to meet some criteria, then be able to access the matched one outside the loop?

Comment: Yes. I totally understand you. You did what was easier and it works well. Though I think I answered your question. With my solution, you can access this date outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following **pseudo-code**:

```
$yourMatchedFile = null;
foreach($dirlist as $f) {
    if($f is good enough!!) {
        $yourMatchedFile = $f;
        break;
    }
}

if(isset($yourMatchedFile)) {
     DoWhatever();
}
```